# Can you still earn Steam achievements after victory?

Tags: achievements, endless-space

Once you've won Endless Space somehow, can you still earn Steam achievements? Or do you have to go back to a saved game before you won, and earn those achievements before your victory?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Having tested this, I can say that yes, you can earn Steam achievements after victory. (I earned "have 1000 science in one system" after finishing a score victory.) You can even get the "Victory via X" conditions after winning; you can win economic, diplomatic, expansion, domination, wonder, and science victories in the same game; the game won't show a victory screen, but you'll get the achievement.

Comment: OMG ... this makes the "destroy every race" cheevo so much more achievable.

Comment: What about after another race's victory?